# How to change the app setting section value during publish .net core project to azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

i am try to publish my live setting to the azure, the current framework i use is .net core 3.0. However during the publishing, i am unable to change others value than the database connection as the image follow[image]

i have others section value in my app setting however i unable to change it, may i know how to publish .net core project with others section value?

Answer (score 0):

Before click publish, you should click the "Edit Azure App Service Settings" options under the Action. The screenshot as blow:

[image]

Comment: Hi ,this is my interface... cannot found that azure app services settings,
https://i.postimg.cc/4ykHCmxL/Annotation-2020-08-17-110656.png

Comment: @ryan1555, which version of visual studio you're using?

Comment: @ryan1555, I did check in community version VS. The option is there. Can you please let me know how did you publish the web app, like the steps?

Comment: right click project , publish, probably is the azure app services setting?

Comment: @ryan1555, right click the project -> publish -> start -> in the "pick a public target " popup, select "App Service", right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219945/discussion-between-ryan1555-and-ivan-yang).

Comment: @ryan1555, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks:).